# How to collectively set the values of multiple columns for certain selected rows for Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` which has `'TPrice','THigh','TLow','TOpen','TClose','TPCLOSE'` columns, and now I want to set `'TPrice','THigh','TLow','TOpen','TClose'` columns values to be same as `'TPCLOSE'` column for the rows whose `TPrice` column value is zero.

Show some rows whose TPrice is 0:

```
>>> df[df['TPrice']==0][['TPrice','THigh','TLow','TOpen','TClose','TPCLOSE']][0:5]
    TPrice  THigh  TLow  TOpen  TClose  TPCLOSE
13       0      0     0      0       0     4.19
19       0      0     0      0       0     7.74
32       0      0     0      0       0     3.27
43       0      0     0      0       0    12.98
60       0      0     0      0       0     7.48
```

Then assignment :

```
>>> df[df['TPrice']==0][['TPrice','THigh','TLow','TOpen','TClose']] = df['TPCLOSE']
```

But Pandas doesn't really change df , for below code still can find some rows:

```
>>> df[df['TPrice']==0][['TPrice','THigh','TLow','TOpen','TClose','TPCLOSE']][0:5]
    TPrice  THigh  TLow  TOpen  TClose  TPCLOSE
13       0      0     0      0       0     4.19
19       0      0     0      0       0     7.74
32       0      0     0      0       0     3.27
43       0      0     0      0       0    12.98
60       0      0     0      0       0     7.48
```

So how to do ?

**Update for Jeff solution:**

```
>>> quote_df = get_quote()
>>> quote_df[quote_df['TPrice']==0][['TPrice','THigh','TLow','TOpen','TClose','TPCLOSE','RT','TVol']][0:5]
    TPrice  THigh  TLow  TOpen  TClose  TPCLOSE   RT  TVol
13       0      0     0      0       0     4.19 -100     0
32       0      0     0      0       0     3.27 -100     0
43       0      0     0      0       0    12.98 -100     0
45       0      0     0      0       0    26.74 -100     0
60       0      0     0      0       0     7.48 -100     0
>>> row_selection = quote_df['TPrice']==0
>>> col_selection = ['THigh','TLow','TOpen','TClose']
>>> for col in col_selection:
...     quote_df.loc[row_selection, col] = quote_df['TPCLOSE']
... 
>>> quote_df[quote_df['TPrice']==0][['TPrice','THigh','TLow','TOpen','TClose','TPCLOSE','RT','TVol']][0:5]
    TPrice  THigh  TLow  TOpen  TClose  TPCLOSE   RT  TVol
13       0   4.19  4.19   4.19    4.19     4.19 -100     0
32       0   4.19  4.19   4.19    4.19     3.27 -100     0
43       0   4.19  4.19   4.19    4.19    12.98 -100     0
45       0   4.19  4.19   4.19    4.19    26.74 -100     0
60       0   4.19  4.19   4.19    4.19     7.48 -100     0
>>>
```

Comment: you are doing a chained assignment and thus modifyig a copy, see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy); try ``df.loc[rows_selector,columns_selector] = ...``

Comment: I try to do : df.loc[df['TPrice']==0,['THigh','TLow','TOpen','TClose']] = df['TPCLOSE'] , but TLow,TOpen,TClose not set the same value as TPCLOSE .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This operation is not automatically broadcast, so you need to do something like this

```
In [17]: df = DataFrame(dict(A = [1,2,0,0,0],B=[0,0,0,10,11],C=[3,4,5,6,7]))

In [18]: df
Out[18]: 
   A   B  C
0  1   0  3
1  2   0  4
2  0   0  5
3  0  10  6
4  0  11  7
```

Compute which rows you want to mask first (otherwise they might change as you go)
if you are modifying A (as you are here)

```
In [19]: mask = df['A'] == 0

In [20]: for col in ['A','B']:
   ....:     df.loc[mask,col] = df['C']
   ....:     

In [21]: df
Out[21]: 
   A  B  C
0  1  0  3
1  2  0  4
2  5  5  5
3  6  6  6
4  7  7  7
```

This requires a change to make it more natural (as you are assigning a series on the rhs to a dataframe on the lhs, which right now doesn't broadcast like you would think it should)
https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5206

Comment: I follow your method, but the dataframe just copy a single value 4.19 to all cells instead of a series of values , pls refer to the "Update for Jeff solution". (I pickle the dataframe quote_df at http://yunpan.cn/Qb2kAabL27DtB ). Don't know why. (Pandas 0.11.0)

Comment: you need 0.12, 0.11 broken for things like this

Comment: ok.I will have a upgrade as 0.13 is available. Thanks. Now I have to one by one set as: row_selection = quote_df['TPrice']==0;value_set = quote_df['TPCLOSE'];quote_df.TOpen[row_selection]  = value_set;quote_df.THigh[row_selection]  = value_set

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> test=pd.DataFrame({'A': [0,1,2], 'B': [3,4,5], 'C': [6,7,8]})
>>> test
   A  B  C
0  0  3  6
1  1  4  7
2  2  5  8
>>> test.apply(lambda x: x.where(test.A!=0, test.C), axis=0)
   A  B  C
0  6  6  6
1  1  4  7
2  2  5  8
```